# Get all sub items that contain user id in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to show all friend requests of the current user by searching through the firebase db and matching on the user id under the receiver node but keep returning nothing.How do i filter by user id in the receiver node ?

```
    public void searchForPendingFriendRequests(){
    mUserFriendsReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("friend_request/receiver" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    mUserFriendsReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() != 0) {
                mPendingFriendsCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAllRequestsText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    FriendRequest friendRequest = child.getValue(FriendRequest.class);
                    friendToAdd = friendRequest.getSender();
                    populateCurrentAddFriendData(friendRequest);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

db looks like this friend_request ---> {pushid} ---> receiver ---> userid

[image]

Comment: you only want to get the `userid`?

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Can I offer another database structure?

Comment: Sure I am new to Firebase so this was my first attempt at it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add this `"/"` in the mUserFriendsReference
Change this line

```
  mUserFriendsReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("friend_request/receiver" +FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

to this

```
  mUserFriendsReference =mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("friend_request/receiver/" +FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```